# My paths in jsconfig file are not working

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the following project structure:

```
-- src
   -- components
   -- contexts
   -- containers
jsconfig.json
```

And I'm trying to create alias for each folder like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "target": "es6",
        "paths": {
            "@Containers/*": ["src/containers/*"],
            "@Components/*": ["src/components/*"],
            "@Contexts/*": ["src/context/*"]
          }
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I'm receiving the following errors:

[image]

For all the imports (not just the @Contexts, it's just a scrolling thing).

But it doesn't mind what I try. I changed the baseUrl to `./`, `.`... but with no luck.
Any idea on why it's not working?